# Oracle APEX 5.1 Selecting Specific Tab in a Tab Container

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have an Oracle APEX 5.1 page that has Static content that uses the Template Tabs Container.

```
TAB 1. TAB 2
```

TAB 2 has a submit button that saves items on the page and then reloads the page.  When I do this action, I would like the TAB 2 to remain selected.  What happens is that the page is submitted and then of coarse reloaded with TAB 1 selected.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have 5.1 any more. However: within **attributes**, you should be able to find a property whose name is **remember active tab** - set it to "Yes". That should do what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I needed to change the Template to Tab and then the appropriate options were available.  Thanks so much for the suggestion.